# Angular4 complains of center element in HTML as undefined function

Tags: javascript, html, angular

What other tag can I use in place of `<center> <\center>` as angular4 complains that center is an undefined function

Answer (score 2):

**TRY 1**  Edit

```
<center>This text will be centered.
<p>So will this paragraph.</p></center>
```

**TRY 2** (CSS alternative) Edit

```
<div style="text-align:center">This text will be centered.
<p>So will this paragraph.</p></div>
```

**TRY 3** (CSS alternative) Edit

```
<p style="text-align:center">This line will be centered.<br>
And so will this line.</p>
```

I hope this helped.